# corrupted double link list detected

Tags: c, linux, memory, ptrace, page-fault

So here is the setup, I have two nodes Node-A & Node-B. Node-A is incapable of executing some functions, whereas Node-B is dedicated for executing such Node-A's incapable functions. So the idea is when Node-A when wants to execute such functions that it is incapable of executing it, I will transfer the stack, heap & process's registers over to the Node-B and execute the function from there. Once Node-B is done with its execution I would transfer it back to the Node-A for usual execution. Furthermore, I have also disabled ASLR (Address space layout randomization) for uniform memory layout across Nodes & stack canary for stack migrations.

Now, the problem which I am facing right now is, while I transfer the stack, heap & processes register back to Node-A from Node-B post special function execution, I getting **corrupted double-linked list** error in the child process.

**I need to find a way to figure what kinda error it is & what am I doing wrong here?**

*Note: Since both of the applications in the nodes are managed by monitor processes using ptrace api, using gdb to figure out the nature of the problem is not an option here, I guess*

**Node-A output:**

```
INFO  Connecting as a client to 192.168.211.128:10001   at __connect_as_client (dsm_handler.c:35)
INFO  Connection established with the server   at __connect_as_client (dsm_handler.c:52)
corrupted double-linked list
```

**Node-B output:**

```
Running in simulation mode
INFO  Setting up the node as server   at dsm_main (dsm_handler.c:137)
INFO  Establishing the node as server at port 10001   at __connect_as_server (dsm_handler.c:81)
INFO  Server waiting for connections   at __connect_as_server (dsm_handler.c:94)
INFO  Connection established with client   at __connect_as_server (dsm_handler.c:103)
Hello world from the enclave
HelloworldEnclave called into host to print: Hello World!
```

Comment: Are you _required_ to do it this way [as a school assignment]? The method you're using is _very_ problematic. What you're trying to do is the equivalent of a "remote procedure call". The usual way is to marshal/serialize the _relevant_ data and send a message to the other process (and get back a response message and unmarshal/deserialize the result). There's almost no way to "inject" a message in this way to a _running_ process and get it to work. If you _must_, we'd need to see the full/relevant code. And, usually, doing such "process migration" usually requires that the kernel do this.

Comment: If you *need* to do something like this **use shared memory** and do not arbitrarily disable ASLR. Shunting memory around from process to process like this, even if it did work, would be close to the worst way imaginable to perform this kind of operation. It's like ordering a pen from Amazon by having *all of Amazon* delivered to your house, picking out the pen, then throwing the whole warehouse out.

Comment: This is a part of a research that I am doing, my plan is use userfaultfds in the future to make sure only the relevant pages are transferred between the nodes, so I guess the problem of bulk sharing would almost be reduced @tadman. In addition to that I cannot serialize or use shared memory as I have to support numerous application of different nature, and I kinda also want this remote execution to be transparent i.e zero changes in the application side.

Comment: Hi @CraigEstey, Here is the link and popsgx_monitor.c is where I do all such manipulations. https://github.com/abiabilesh/popSGX_Monitor_uffd/blob/stack-migration/src/popsgx_monitor.c. If you want we can also connect via zoom & kindly help me to figure it out.

Comment: You're going to be fighting against every OS mitigation method that goes to great lengths to render what you're trying to do impossible. While it's completely bizarre to want to do this, you should be able to make modifications remotely so long as you use *existing pointers only*.